# is it possible to keep the original file tab when replace text using sed

Tags: bash, shell

I am using sed to replace some text in shell script, this is the original file looks like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /api/test {
        proxy_connect_timeout 3000;
        proxy_send_timeout 3000;
        proxy_read_timeout 3000;
        send_timeout 3000;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        client_body_buffer_size 100M;
        proxy_pass http://www.1.com;
    }

    location /api/demo {
        proxy_connect_timeout 3000;
        proxy_send_timeout 3000;
        proxy_read_timeout 3000;
        send_timeout 3000;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        client_body_buffer_size 100M;
        proxy_pass http://www.2.com;
    }
}
```

and this is my shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u

set -e

# set -x

echo "please input url1:"

read URL1

echo "plase input url2:"

read URL2

URL1_ESCAPED_REPLACE=$(printf '%s\n' "$URL1" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')

URL2_ESCAPED_REPLACE=$(printf '%s\n' "$URL2" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')

timestamp=$(date +%s)

sed -Ei."$timestamp".bak -e "/\/api\/test/,/proxy\_pass/ s/.*proxy\_pass.*/proxy\_pass $URL1_ESCAPED_REPLACE;/" \
-e "/\/api\/demo/,/proxy\_pass/ s/.*proxy\_pass.*/proxy\_pass $URL2_ESCAPED_REPLACE;/" nginx.conf
```

this script works fine but I am facing a problem that, the replace action make the space indent disappear. is it possible just do the replace text without delete the whitle space? I want to keep the original text format.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problem with removing `.*` in `s/.*proxy\_pass` then it should solve your problem.
The problem is that you are specifying to `sed` command to substitute
all string that matches with `.*proxy_pass.*` and `.*` means **any character zero or more times**. So in this case all before and after `proxy_pass` will be removed and therefore the indentation will be removed too.

For solving the problem your `sed` command should be like this:

```
sed -Ei."$timestamp".bak -e "/\/api\/test/,/proxy\_pass/ s/proxy\_pass.*/proxy\_pass $URL1_ESCAPED_REPLACE;/" \
-e "/\/api\/demo/,/proxy\_pass/ s/proxy\_pass.*/proxy\_pass $URL2_ESCAPED_REPLACE;/" nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an starting `.*` will select everything before the text matched, including spaces. If you replace that for a fixed text `proxy_pass` then all leading spaces will get erased. You could just change the replacement command to retain the spaces (with a `\1`).

So your code will become:

```
timestamp=$EPOCHSECONDS

sed -Ei."$timestamp".bak -e "/\/api\/test/,/proxy_pass/ s/(.*proxy_pass).*/\1 $URL1_ESCAPED_REPLACE;/" \
-e   "/\/api\/demo/,/proxy_pass/ s/(.*proxy_pass).*/\1 $URL2_ESCAPED_REPLACE;/" infile
```